# How to declare a function inside a kernel function in OpenCL?

Tags: c, indexing, opencl

I want to define a function within a kernel function to make my indexing code clearer:

```
kernel void do_something (const int some_offset,
                          const int other_offset,
                          global float* buffer)
{
    int index(int x, int y)
    {
        return some_offset+other_offset*x+y;
    }

    float value = buffer[index(1,2)];
    ...
}
```

Otherwise I'd have to declare the index function outside of my kernel and index like

```
float value = buffer[index(1,2,some_offset,other_offset)];
```

which would make it more ugly etc. Is there any way to do this? The compiler gives me an an error, saying:

```
OpenCL Compile Error: clBuildProgram failed (CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE).
Line 5: error: expected a ";"
```

Is it possible to do what I want or is there a different way to achieve the same?
Thanks!

Comment: C doesn't have any kind of closure. I assume OpenCL doesn't either, but since it's (originally) an Apple thing, check to see whether you can use [blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29). Failing that, in this case it looks as though you *could* use a macro, since your `some_offset` remains in scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C doesn't support nested functions.  However, your case is simple enough to be implemented with a macro:

```
#define index(x,y) some_offset+other_offset*(x)+(y)
```

The parentheses around x and y are crucial to make the macro do what you want if you pass it more complicated expressions, e.g., `index(a+b,c)`.

Comment: Sounds great. Do I have to define the Macro inside my kernel function or does it not matter where I define it?

Comment: In C, preprocessing is a separate compilation phase that happens before compiling. So you can define it anywhere before the first use. (Maybe OpenCL has more restrictions.)

Comment: You should also put parens around the whole expression: `(some_offset+other_offset*(x)+(y))`. Otherwise `index(x,y)*2` does something surprising.